# Chrome Extension's Content Script catch custom events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If we are firing a custom event from the page, can a content script injected into the page catch that event and process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, content script can communicate with the injected web page. Because the context of content script and injected web page are isolated from each other, they must communicate with shared DOM.

I think content script can't catch the custom event which was fired by injected page directly. But you can post message to content script when specific custom event is fired. window.postMessage can fit your needs.

Injected page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">test</button>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $(document).trigger("MY_EVENT");
        });
        $(document).on("MY_EVENT",function(){
            window.postMessage({ type: "HELLO", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Script:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

    if (event.source != window)
    return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "HELLO")) {
        alert("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
    }
}, false);
```

Hope this is helpful for you.